# Issue Installing sfdx-plugin-source-read via sf plugins install

Tags: sf, plugin

I hope this message finds you well. I am encountering an issue while attempting to install the [`sfdx-plugin-source-read`](https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-plugin-source-read) plugin using the following command:

```bash
sf plugins install sfdx-plugin-source-read
```

However, I am consistently receiving the following error:

```bash
Installing plugin sfdx-plugin-source-read@latest... failed
 ›   Warning: (node:2890) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling 
 ›   certificate verification.
    Error: /Users/ea_enel/.local/share/sf/client/2.23.20-50cd2d8/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js add sfdx-plugin-source-read@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:/Users/ea_enel/.local/share/sf/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=/Users/ea_enel/Library/Caches/sf/yarn --check-files exited with code 1
```

Additionally, I have attempted to resolve the issue by deleting the `~/.local/share/sf/yarn.lock` file, as suggested in other related issues.
Then update Salesforce CLI version to 2.26.10 (currently the last one) but the result is still the same.

Any guidance or assistance you can provide in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Emanuele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, in my case it turned out that the problem was linked to the company VPN which prevents Yalm from downloading the files it needs.

If you encounter similar problems, check that packets are not blocked in the connection being established.

Here begins my discussion with the plugin maintainer:
https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-plugin-source-read/issues/87